# Render strings on a cshtml from a class with constants

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a public class like this:

```
namespace MyProgram.Common
{
     public static class UIStrings
     {
          public const string Title = "Hellow World"
          public const string SubTitle = "This is another string. Please click on '<a href=\"/Home/Status\" target=\"_blank">Here</a>'"
     }
}
```

And then, on my Index.csthml I have the following code:

```
<label id="title" for="MyTitle">@Myprogram.Common.UiStrings.Title </label>
<label id="title" for="SubTitle">@Myprogram.Common.UiStrings.SubTitle </label>
```

The title renders fine but the link that I defined in the Subtitle doesn't render as a link but as the string itself.

Is there a way this can be done? I want to avoid to hardcode the strings in the cshtml file...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

User Html.Raw

```
<label id="title" for="MyTitle">@Myprogram.Common.UiStrings.Title </label>
<label id="title" for="SubTitle">@Html.Raw(Myprogram.Common.UiStrings.SubTitle) </label>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the HTML decode function. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
This will force the browser to interpret the output as HTML rather than as a string.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! I tried that but it didn't seem to work for me. I used the Html.Raw function and worked though.